# How do I display HTML entities as text?

Tags: php, html, entity

I'm building an ASCII binary decoder. I need to know how to show an HTML entity such as &#035 ; as text in an HTML document instead of the character it corresponds to.

Comment: you can always use &amp; for the ampersand and then use the rest of the code... so &amp;#035 ; = &#035 ;

Comment: There are some entities that don't have names like &amp; they just have numbers like &#035; I need to use some that don't have names. How would I display that as text?

Comment: view the source of any web  page that displays the entities

Comment: If the `&amp;` isn’t a solution, then your intended question seems to be different from what you actually asked.

Comment: HTML entities coded in numbers are not ASCII; They are Unicode codepoints. Unicode is a superset of ASCII with matching codepoints.

Comment: I know that, but I need to show the HTML entity to a person if they are decoding a binary code. This is because is isn't always evident what is being decoded. For instance if you decode 00011000 as &#024; it will be executed as HTML and you won't know that it means cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are about htmlentities() function in PHP

[PHP manual about htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)